# Inserting entrywise

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list

```
m={a,b,c,d};
```

How can I insert $==0$ to get list of equations so that the function Solve can take it as an argument?

```
m={a==0,b==0,c==0,d==0}
```

How to remove curly brackets to get?

```
m=a==0,b==0,c==0,d==0
```

Comment: `eqs = Thread[Equal[m, 0]]`

Comment: `eqs = # == 0 & /@ m`

Comment: The OP could have received many more answers by waiting a bit before accepting an answer. Its a good idea to wait until you have tested answers befor voting them, and wait further 24hours for other answers before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD) the best one, giving time to other people to contribute.

Comment: Anybody can do one using `ReaplaceAll`?

Comment: `Replace[m, a_ -> a == 0, 1]`

Comment: `m /. {List -> List, a_Symbol -> a == 0}`

Comment: @Syed if you compose an answer I'd be happy to upvote it. Better than upvoting each comment to be honest :-)

Comment: You could also represent this with one equation: `Norm[m,1]==0` because it's equivalent to `Abs[a]+Abs[b]+Abs[c]+Abs[d] == 0` which is only true when a,b,c,d are all zero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following

```
Thread[Flatten /@ (m == Table[0, Length@m])]

MapThread[Equal, {m, Table[0, Length@m]}]

Inner[Equal, m, Table[0, Length@m], List]

Equal @@@ Transpose[{m, Table[0, Length@m]}]

Internal`InheritedBlock[{Equal}, SetAttributes[Equal, Listable];
 m == Table[0, Length@m]]
```

> [image: res]

Edit:

About the second part of the question... I don't really understand what you mean. Perhaps the following?

```
Extract[1]@{a == 0, b == 0, c == 0, d == 0}
```

> [image: res2]

Comment: Very nice, [InheritedBlock](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/InheritedBlock/) is also a resource function from Wolfram research. The possible issues section can be interesting.

Answer (score 6):

```
eqns = Table[lhs == 0, {lhs, m}]

eqns = Map[EqualTo[0],m]

eqns = Thread[Equal[m, 0]] (* Credit Syed *)
```

To use as arguments you can do

```
f[1,2,Sequence@@eqns]
```

Comment: @bmf just updated to address that.

Comment: yes, just saw that :-)